# Notes 9: Add button to IMAP nsf

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I have configured Notes 9 to read email from localhost using IMAP and SMTP. Using steps from https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUev8-vLETKhU/?hl=sl chapter "COMPLETE STEP BY STEP GUIDE ON HOW TO CONFIGURE GMAIL IMAP ON LOTUS NOTES 8x".

How can I add a button to the form which displays an email?

What I have done so far:

I have preformed the steps in the guide mentioned above in order to read email from an IMAP server which does not require encryption (SSL or TLS). This has created the file (database) "InClear.nsf". In Notes, I open InClear.nsf in order to read and receive email. Receiving and reading email works correctly.

I start IBM Domino Designer and edit file InClear.nsf. It tells me that the design is inherited from master template StdR50IMail. Template version is 6.0 (2005.05.23).

I edit in IBM Domino Designer the file "imapcl5.ntf". It says that this is the master template "stdR50lMail". I edit "imapcl5.ntf" > Forms > "Memo", I edit it as needed.

What should I do next in order to see my changes in "IBM Notes" when I read may IMAP email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local databases you could have just ignored the warning that the database inherits its design from a template and edit the database in designer directly.

Now that you chnaged the template you just need to refresh the design of „Inclear.nsf“:

- open the database in client
- Make sure that advanced menus are enabled (View - advanced menus)
- Click on menu file - database - refresh design
- Select „Local“ and klick ok...

Then your button will be there.

Comment: Please disregard my entire issue.

The problem was generated by the fact that I did a copy for backup purposes of the *.ntf file. So I had two *.ntf files with the same "Database file is a master template Template name:":

c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\Data\imapcl5.ntf
c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\Data\imapcl5 - Copy_orig.ntf